# MongoDB - rename a column name that matches a regex

Tags: mongodb

I have a column name in a collection that accidentally has two variable bytes, resulting in several columns for the same data instead of one column :

```
{"_id":"5f9c48a311a707ea4af164f0", "rx packet value (location AD)":"0xdeadbeef" }
{"_id":"5f9c48a311a707ea4af164f1", "rx packet value (location BD)":"0xdeadbabe" }
{"_id":"5f9c48a311a707ea4af164f2", "rx packet value (location 0D)":"0xcafecafe" }
{"_id":"5f9c48a311a707ea4af164f3", "rx packet value (location FD)":"0xbabababa" }
```

i would like to rename all these columns with one common name, like this :

```
db.my_collection.updateMany( {}, {$rename:{/column_name(variable_bytes)/:"column_name"}}, false, true)'
```

But the `$rename` operator takes a column name, not a regex.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Can you show a couple of sample documents?

Comment: Yes i added a sample with the problematic column only.